# How to send process in background which has not started from shell?

Tags: shell

I know how to send process to background and foreground which has started through shell using `bg` and `fg` commands.

How can I send process which has started by clicking icons or menu? like I open firefox from menu and I want to send this opened firefox to background and to foreground when I would want?

I could not found man page of `bg`.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr I don't think you can.

`fg` and `bg` (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>) interact with processes started by the *current shell* ("jobs"), and it would be a security issue if a shell could take over a job of another shell.

See the "job control" section of `man bash` for details.